# 'List of tables' pages overlapping with 'list of tables continued'

Tags: table-of-contents

I have almost 15 tables, including tables in the appendix. So I need to list "list of tables" in two pages in the "table of contents". Currently, the problem is, latex class file provided by my university is unable to handle the second page of tables and it is overlapping the first page of the table onto the second one refer to the image below.

I have tried and failed with below commands

```
\cleardoublepage
and 
\renewcommand{\cleardoublepage}{}
and
\makeatletter
\pretocmd{\@table}{\begingroup \renewcommand{\thetable}{\NUMBERstring{Table}}}{}{}
\apptocmd{\@Table}{\endgroup}{}{}
\makeatother
```

I have deadline to submit my thesis, I would love to hear back any possible solution sooner.

Below is my current table of contents latex code:

```
% Table of contents
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{TABLE OF CONTENTS}
\setlength{\cftbeforetoctitleskip}{-7.5pt}
\setlength{\cftaftertoctitleskip}{0.38in}
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\hfill\normalfont\MakeUppercase}
\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{\hfill}
\cftsetpnumwidth{0in}
\cftsetrmarg{2in}

% Chapter formatting in TOC
\renewcommand{\cftchapindent}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\cftchapnumwidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{\MakeUppercase{chapter}~}
\renewcommand{\cftchapaftersnumb}{\nopagebreak \\}
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\cftchappagefont}{\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\cftbeforechapskip}{1pc}

\makeatletter
\pretocmd{\@chapter}{\begingroup \renewcommand{\thechapter}{\NUMBERstring{chapter}}}{}{}
\apptocmd{\@chapter}{\endgroup}{}{}
\makeatother

% Section formatting in TOC
\renewcommand{\cftsecindent}{0.88in}
\renewcommand{\cftsecnumwidth}{0.37in}
\renewcommand{\cftsecpresnum}{}
\renewcommand{\cftsecaftersnum}{.~}
\renewcommand{\cftsecfont}{\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\cftsecpagefont}{\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\cftbeforesecskip}{1pc}

% Subsection formatting in TOC
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecindent}{1.19in}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecnumwidth}{0.55in}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecpresnum}{}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecaftersnum}{.}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecfont}{\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecpagefont}{\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\cftbeforesubsecskip}{1pc}
\renewcommand{\cleardoublepage}{}

% List of figures 
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{LIST OF FIGURES}
\renewcommand{\cftloftitlefont}{\hfill\normalfont\MakeUppercase}
\renewcommand{\cftafterloftitle}{\hfill}
\setlength{\cftbeforeloftitleskip}{-0.07in}
\setlength{\cftafterloftitleskip}{0.55in}
\renewcommand{\cftdot}{}
\renewcommand{\cftfigpresnum}{Figure }
\renewcommand{\cftfigindent}{0pc}
\renewcommand{\cftfignumwidth}{1.0in}
\renewcommand{\cftfigafterpnum}{\vspace{12pt}}

% List of tables
\renewcommand{\listtablename}{LIST OF TABLES}
\renewcommand{\cftlottitlefont}{\hfill\normalfont\MakeUppercase}
\renewcommand{\cftafterlottitle}{\hfill}
\setlength{\cftbeforelottitleskip}{-0.1in}
\setlength{\cftafterlottitleskip}{0.55in}
\renewcommand{\cftdot}{}
\renewcommand{\cfttabpresnum}{Table }
\renewcommand{\cfttabindent}{0pc}
\renewcommand{\cfttabnumwidth}{1in}
\renewcommand{\cfttabafterpnum}{\vspace*{12pt}}

% Redefine chapter to not put extra line in lof and lot
\def\@chapter[#1]#2{\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
                       \if@mainmatter
                         \refstepcounter{chapter}%
                         \typeout{\@chapapp\space\thechapter.}%
                         \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}%
                                   {\protect\numberline{\thechapter}#1}%
                       \else
                         \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}%
                       \fi
                    \else
                      \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}%
                    \fi
                    \chaptermark{#1}%
%                       These lines are commented out to not put space                    
%                    \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}
%                    \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}
                    \if@twocolumn
                      \@topnewpage[\@makechapterhead{#2}]%
                    \else
                      \@makechapterhead{#2}%
                      \@afterheading
                    \fi}

% Glossary
\newglossarystyle{grizz_glossary}{
\renewcommand{\glossaryname}{\vspace*{0.2in}LIST OF ABBREVIATIONS}
 % put the glossary in the tabular environment:  
 \renewenvironment{theglossary}%  
   {\noindent\begin{longtable}{p{1.13in}p{4.37in}}}{\end{longtable}}%  
 % have nothing after \begin{theglossary}:  
 \renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{}%  
 % have nothing between glossary groups:  
 \renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1]{}%  
 \renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{}%  

 \renewcommand*{\glossaryentryfield}[5]{  
        \glstarget{##1}{##2}\hfill & ##3\hfill \vspace{12pt}\\
 }   
}

% Fancy header styles

\addtolength{\textheight}{-0.05in}
\fancypagestyle{tocstyle}{
\fancyhf{}
\lhead{}
\rhead{}
\chead{TABLE OF CONTENTS---Continued}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\addtolength{\topmargin}{0.57in}
\addtolength{\headsep}{0.28in}
\addtolength{\textheight}{-0.85in}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
}

\fancypagestyle{lofstyle}{
\fancyhf{}
\lhead{}
\rhead{}
\chead{LIST OF FIGURES---Continued}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\addtolength{\topmargin}{0.57in}
\addtolength{\headsep}{0.28in}
\addtolength{\textheight}{-0.85in}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
}

\addtolength{\textheight}{-0.05in}
\fancypagestyle{lotstyle}{
\fancyhf{}
\lhead{}
\rhead{}
\chead{LIST OF TABLES---Continued}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\addtolength{\topmargin}{0.57in}
\addtolength{\headsep}{0.28in}
\addtolength{\textheight}{-0.85in}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
}
```

[image: current list of tables problem]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! What is the problem with the list of tables being on two pages? Is it that the text "LIST OF TABLES" is printed twice?

Comment: Thank you! The First page "List of tables" is supposed to be one page, if I add few more tables to the thesis, the "list of tables - continued" is triggered but the content of the first page is appearing in the second page including the header "list of tables". The extra tables are overflowing and not appearing in this second page. The first "list of tables" is a blank page as a result, and the second page contains part of the tables as show in the image. I hope I did not confuse. Let me know if you need more information.